# using rolling functions, in pandas, with a series where the time index is very sparse

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series where the index is in milliseconds and is quite sparse. You can have many entries a few ms apart and nothing for seconds.

I would like to compute a rolling min / max, but I can't get it to work.

The index is built that way:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
```

First I tried this:

```
df['rolling_low'] = df['price'].rolling('1m').min()
```

but then I get this error:

> window must be an integer

looking at various posts, I tried this:

```
df['rolling_low'] = df.rolling('1m', on='timestamp')['price'].min()
```

for some reason, it has a different syntax than the first try, but anyhow, it give me:

> timestamp must be monotonic

Another search on SO and I added this:

```
df = df.sort_index()
```

but it's still the same problem.

This issue seems very unclear to me: I don't really understand the error message, I also don't understand the difference between the two syntax I have found and I don't really find much documentation about this error, besides a couple of online posts with the same problem and no solution that works in my case.

What does the error mean exactly? and, additionally, how do I fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following: `df['rolling_low'] = df['price'].rolling('1m').min()` you've got to make sure that
your timestamp is the index of the dataframe. This is done in: `df = df.set_index("timestamp")`
in the code example below, otherwise you will get `﻿ValueError: window must be an integer` error.
I agree the error is quite nebulous in this context. Here's a working example :)

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [
            "2020-04-20 12:00:00.123",
            "2020-04-20 12:00:00.126",
            "2020-04-20 12:00:00.128",
            "2020-04-20 12:00:05.126",
            "2020-04-20 12:00:05.140",
            "2020-04-20 12:00:05.156",
            "2020-04-20 12:00:12.126",
            "2020-04-20 12:00:12.129",
        ],
        "price": range(8),
    }
)
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df = df.set_index("timestamp")
df["rolling_low"] = df["price"].rolling("1s").min()
```

Output:

```
﻿                         price  rolling_low
timestamp
2020-04-20 12:00:00.123      0          0.0
2020-04-20 12:00:00.126      1          0.0
2020-04-20 12:00:00.128      2          0.0
2020-04-20 12:00:05.126      3          3.0
2020-04-20 12:00:05.140      4          3.0
2020-04-20 12:00:05.156      5          3.0
2020-04-20 12:00:12.126      6          6.0
2020-04-20 12:00:12.129      7          6.0
```

If you want to do 1 minute aggregations use "60s" as the arg to `rolling`.